# How to remove CSS indentation in Google Chrome Inspector (Developer tools)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, inspector

I know that we can select 2,4,8 spaces or tab, but I want to remove totally any indentation when I am copying css code from the Chrome Inspector, 
it is possible?
Thanks

I mean, copying the css from the right side of the Inspector , when I paste it to a code editor, it comes with indentation, I want to copy without that indentation
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the CSS is already formatted to your liking, except that it has the unwanted indentation characters. You may want to press the Auto Format button (it looks like <kbd>{ }</kbd>) on the bottom left of the Sources status bar. (See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#format.)

In the Sources tab in Dev Tools, select the portion of CSS you want to copy, then hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key then push the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key once. You may need to do this a few times to remove all the indentation, especially if there are nested at-rules like `@media`. (If the file is large, it may take a few moments to update the view in the Sources tab.) Then proceed as normal by copying the selected code.

Answer (score 0):

This has been bugging me for years, and I finally figured it out. In Chrome Dev Tools Settings > Preferences set the Default indentation to "Tab character".

I think that option didn't used to be there but it is now and removed the annoying indentation when copy / pasting

Comment: For some reason the problem came back recently and I had to disable "Detect indentation" in Settings > Preferences which sorts it.